# SQL DB2 : unexpected result using min(date)

Tags: sql, db2

here is the offending script:

```
select distinct person, min(pdate) as min_date from db
where ptype like 'A1%'
or (ptype like 'B1%'
and (pdate between '2000-01-01' and '2001-01-01'))
group by person
```

The problem

The min_date retreived also include those outisde of the pdates I have specified. However when I take out one of the ptypes so I have:

```
select distinct person, min(pdate) as min_date from db
where ptype like 'A1%'
and (pdate between '2000-01-01' and '2001-01-01')
group by person
```

then this problem goes away. Why is it that introducing a second ptype is retuning instances outside of the pdates i have specified?

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, please never use `BETWEEN`, even for dates - it doesn't work nicely with timestamps.  For instance... in your statement you'll end up with `pDate`s for all of 2000, as well as for January 1st, 2001.  If `pDate` is actually a timestamp, this will be `2001-01-01 00:00:00.000000` only, which still is aggravating.  Please see [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for more (although some of that is SQL Server specific, the general concepts apply).

Answer (score 5):

It's because your existing query is of the form:

```
IF A or (B and D)
```

- so if A is true, D is ignored. You actually want a query of the form:

```
IF (A or B) and D
```

like so:

```
select distinct person, min(pdate) as min_date from db
where (ptype like 'A1%' or ptype like 'B1%') and 
      pdate between '2000-01-01' and '2001-01-01'
group by person
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct person, min(pdate) as min_date from db
where (      ptype like 'A1%'
         or (ptype like 'B1%'))
and (pdate between '2000-01-01' and '2001-01-01')
group by person
```

One ) was falsh?